# Microsoft Access - Progress bar when running a single query

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, progress-bar, percentage

I've seen a number threads / forums with examples of progress bars in access databases which unfortunately hasn't resolved my issue.

I know Access has a small status bar that shows you the progress of the running query but this is not adequate for my needs.

Is it possible to show on a popup form a progress bar of the current (single) query that is running? displaying the percentage of how much of the query has been processed?

or perhaps would it be possible to display the status bar in a popup form?

Many thanks
Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do either.

For a single query, all there is is the internal, automatic progress bar.

Custom, manual progress bars are only possible if you have multiple actions (like a loop).

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me...I've given up on that idea now